# How can one make an ordered list in HTML/CSS with sub-lists with combined number/letter identifiers?

Tags: css, sass, html-lists

*Edit:   Down-vote message received (I should have made and posted some attempt at solving the problem), lesson learned, so I'd appreciate not being down-voted any more....*

A friend asked me to do a simple web page for them and I'm stumped at one thing -- I want to do an ordered list within an ordered list, like this:

```
1. something
2. something else
3. something different
  3a. and a sub thing
  3b. and another sub thing
```

But the sub list has to have custom strings as its 'numbers'.  I can figure out to have just letters, but not numbers and letters.

That's it, but after 30 minutes of googling and being perplexed at `counter-increment` and `counter-reset`, I'm wondering if there is a simple way to do this?

Any help much appreciated1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could work with 2 counters, one for letters & one for numbers.

```css
ul{
  padding:0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.root {
  counter-reset: numbers;
}
.root > li::before {
  counter-increment: numbers;
  content: counter(numbers) ". ";
}
.root ul {
  padding-left: 15px;
  counter-reset: letters;
}
.root ul > li::before {
  counter-increment: letters;
  content: counter(numbers) counter(letters, lower-alpha) ". ";
}
```

```html
<ul class="root">
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item
    <ul>
      <li>sub-item</li>
      <li>sub-item</li>
      <li>sub-item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item
    <ul>
      <li>sub-item</li>
      <li>sub-item</li>
      <li>sub-item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item
    <ul>
      <li>sub-item</li>
      <li>sub-item</li>
      <li>sub-item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

With SASS:

```
ul{
  padding:0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.root {
  counter-reset: numbers;
  > li::before {
    counter-increment: numbers;
    content: counter(numbers) ". ";
  }
  ul {
    padding-left: 15px;
    counter-reset: letters;
    > li::before {
      counter-increment: letters;
      content: counter(numbers) counter(letters, lower-alpha) ". ";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick. Note that this is static HTML, you'll have to manually add the number and it is not in any way an automated solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  counter-reset: letter-counter;
}
ul {
list-style-type: none;
}
li li::before {
  counter-increment: letter-counter;
  content: "3" counter(letter-counter, lower-alpha) ". ";
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ol>
<li>item</li>
<li>item</li>
<li>item
<ul><li>sub-item</li>
<li>sub-item</li>
<li>sub-item</li></ul></li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```